# How do I nest layouts with ServiceStack.Razor?

Tags: razor, servicestack

Given the following directory structure (to keep it simple):

```
/
  _Layout.cshtml
  _SubLayout.cshtml
  default.cshtml
  sub.cshtml
```

And contents:

sub.cshtml

```
@inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage
@{Layout = "_SubLayout";}
<div>In the sub folder.</div>
```

_SubLayout.cshtml

```
@inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage
@{Layout = "_Layout";}
<div>This is a page from a sub section:</div>
@RenderBody()
```

How can I render the _SubLayout.cshtml view within the _Layout.cshtml view when a request is made for sub.cshtml? When I do this now only the _SubLayout.cshtml is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported in ServiceStack 3.9.54

Comment: This is working now! One note though (and I think this is a service stack thing): make sure the layouts also have different names regardless of your directory structure.